# How to implement outline entries like those found in an outline

Tags: python, interface

I have a feature that can search for related objects associated with a specified object, similar to Unreal Engine's reference viewer. However, there's an issue: the usability of the user interface is poor, and I would like to implement an outline view effect for better manipulation. After conducting a round of searches on Google, I couldn't find any relevant references or examples. So, I'm wondering if anyone knows how this can be achieved, or whether it's feasible at all.

[image]

The UI code is as follows.

```
import bpy


class VIEW3D_PT_test(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_category = "Test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        def draw_item(layout: bpy.types.UILayout, d, index=0):
            icons = {
                "objects": "OBJECT_DATA",
                "collections": "OUTLINER_COLLECTION",
                "scenes": "SCENE_DATA",
                "mesh": "OUTLINER_OB_MESH",
                "curve": "CURVE_DATA",
            }
            row = layout.row(align=1)
            row.separator(factor=index * 4)
            icon = icons.get(d["type"], "NONE")
            row.label(text=d["name"], icon=icon)
            for i in d["sub"]:
                draw_item(layout, i, index + 1)

        data = {
            "name": "Legend_NvZhanShi_Skeleton",
            "type": "objects",
            "sub": [
                {
                    "name": "coll 12",
                    "type": "collections",
                    "sub": [
                        {
                            "name": "Scene",
                            "type": "scenes",
                            "sub": [],
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
        col = layout.column(align=1)
        draw_item(col, data)
```